# WARN mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Skipping non-directory hdfs: on EMR

Tags: hadoop, hbase, amazon-emr, mapr

I am trying to do bulk load text files using mapreduce in Hbase .
Everything is working fine but when i do bulk load at last step i get warning and my mapreduce job stuck .

```
17/06/15 10:22:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1495181241247_0013 completed successfully
17/06/15 10:22:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=836391
                FILE: Number of bytes written=1988049
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=73198
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=12051358
                HDFS: Number of read operations=8
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=3
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=1
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=196200
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=428490
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4360
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=4761
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4360
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=4761
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=6278400
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=13711680
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=5604
                Map output records=5603
                Map output bytes=8240332
                Map output materialized bytes=836387
                Input split bytes=240
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=5603
                Reduce shuffle bytes=836387
                Reduce input records=5603
                Reduce output records=179296
                Spilled Records=11206
                Shuffled Maps =1
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=1
                GC time elapsed (ms)=137
                CPU time spent (ms)=11240
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=820736000
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=7694557184
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=724566016
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=72958
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=12051358
Incremental upload completed..........
job is successfull..........H file Loading Will start Now
17/06/15 10:22:43 WARN mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Skipping non-directory hdfs://ip:8020/user/hadoop/ESGTRF/outputdir/output0/_SUCCESS
```

Same thing  is working on cloudera but when i run this on AWS EMR i get this issue .

I suspect something with the configuration .
I have not mentioned any configuration explicitly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the permission explicitly my problem resolved

```
hfs.setPermission(new Path(outputPath+"/columnFamilyName"),FsPermission.valueOf("drwxrwxrwx"));
```